# Existence of $K$-invariant complex structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-topology

Let $K$ be a compact connected real Lie group, let $M$ be a symplectic manifold with a symplectic left action of $K$, and let $ω$
be the symplectic structure of $M$.

Does there always exist a $K$-invariant complex structure $J$ on $M$
that it is compatible with $ω$, i.e., such that $g_M (·, ·):=ω_M (·, J ·)$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. I've edited the question so it'll be clearer what are you asking, did I get that right?

Comment: Maybe you knew this already, but in the case when $K$ is a torus, the answer is yes. This is proven in Lemma 5.52 of "Introduction to symplectic topology" Mcduff and Salamon.

Comment: Oh and that assumes the action is Hamiltonian as well...

Comment: You probably mean an almost complex structure. There are symplectic manifolds which do not admit a complex structure.

Comment: Thanks, yes the result I stated was about existence of invariant, compatible, almost complex structure. Just to flesh out abx's example, if $M$ is the Kodaira-Thurston manifold, then $M \times S^{2}$ has a symplectic circle action (product of standard action on $S^2$ and trivial action on $M$) but $b_{1}(M \times S^{2}) = 3$ so it cannot be Kahler (which would be implied by a compatible complex structure).

Comment: In general, a compatible almost complex structure on $(M,ω)$, is the same as a section of $\mathcal F×_{Sp(2n,\mathbb R)}(\frac{Sp(2n,R)}{U(2n)})$where $\mathcal F→M$ is the bundle of symplectic frames on $M $

Comment: If the compact Lie group $K$ act symplectically on $(M,ω)$ then there is a $K$-invariant compatible almost complex structure